# DS18B20 value change with its power

Tags: pi-3b+, ds18b20

I bought 3 DS18B20 and I am trying to use them for my domotics.
I have relilability issue depending on how I power the DS18B20.

The gobal setup :

- 1 MeanWell DR-15-5 to power the Pi
- 1 Raspberry Pi 3 with Homeassistant on it to read and historize the one-wire temp value
- 1 RJ45 CAT7 shielded of 8m long
- 1 External supply of 4.5v
- The GND between the MeanWell, the Pi and later the 4.5v supply are put in common.
- The 3 DS18B20 GND are connected to the common GND through RJ45 cat 7
- The 3 DS18B20 DATA are connected the GPIO4 through RJ45 cat 7
- There is a pull up 4.7kohm resistance between GPIO4 and 3.3v of the Pi
- One Zwave thermometer for comparaison (reference temperature)

The first variation :

- (Blue) reference temperature, zwave thermometer
- (Orange) DS18B20 VCC connected on 5v Meanwell => standard déviation of +-1.5°
- (Cyan) DS18B20 VCC connected on 4.5v external supply => standard déviation of 0.4° and an average below the blue reference > 0.7°
- (Green) DS18B20 VCC connected on 5v Pi => an average below the blue reference > 1.2°

[image: first variation]
Analysis : There are different mean between ech between DS18B20. (Why ? Hint below) There is also a big difference of standard deviation between each thermometer. (Why ? Hint below)

The second variation :

- (Orange) DS18B20 VCC connected on 5v Meanwell => standard déviation of +-0.3° and an average below the blue reference > 0.5°
- (Cyan) DS18B20 VCC connected on 5v Meanwell => standard déviation of +-0.3° and an average below the blue reference > 0.9°
- (Green) DS18B20 VCC connected on 5v Meanwell => standard déviation of +-0.3° and an average below the blue reference > 1.2°

[image: second variation]
Analysis :  The mean of the thermometers are in the same order as before orange > cyan > green. I suspect that each thermometer are not calibrated the same way. It explains the difference between each thermometer.

The standard deviation is the same for each DS18B20. I suspect the standard deviation comes from the power supply. I dont know why..

The mean of the orange DS18B20 in the second variation is more distant from the reference thermometer (blue one) than the the orange from the first variation. Why does the power supply of the DS18B20 influence the mean temperature ?

The third variation :

- (Orange) DS18B20 VCC connected on 5v Pi => an average above the blue reference > 0.2°
- (Cyan) DS18B20 VCC connected on 5v Pi => OK
- (Green) DS18B20 VCC connected on 5v Pi => OK

[image: third variation]
Analysis : Its seems the best configuration to have no standard deviation and a mean close to the blue one.
But there is the same problem as before : the means of the DS18B20 are different for each variation regarding the blue one. The power supply seems to impact the mean.

The fourth variation :

- (Orange) DS18B20 VCC connected on 4.5v external supply => OK
- (Cyan) DS18B20 VCC connected on 4.5v external supply =>  an average above the blue reference > 0.1°
- (Green) DS18B20 VCC connected on 4.5v external supply => an average above the blue reference > 0.3°

[image: fourth variation]
Analysis : the means of the DS18B20 are different for each variation regarding the blue one.

The fifth variation :

- Pi powered by a another power supply (2A smarptohne power supply). The MeanWell power supply is not used anymore by the Pi.
- (Orange) DS18B20 VCC connected on 5v Meanwell => an std dev of 0.1° and means below 0.2 of the blue one°
- (Cyan) DS18B20 VCC connected on 5v Meanwell =>  an std dev of 0.1° and means below 1° of the blue one
- (Green) DS18B20 VCC connected on 5v Meanwell => an std dev of 0.1° and means below 1° of the blue one

[image: fifth variation]
Analysis : It seems that without the Pi, the Meanwell power supply induced less standard deviation in the DS18B20 (about 0.1°). But the means of the DS18B20 regarding the reference thermometer (blue one) is very different from the second experiment.

I want to power the DS18B20 with the 5v MeanWell because I want to use also the 5v to power led in my light switches.
I dont undestand why the power supply influence the temparture reported by the DS18B20.

Comment: "The 3 DS18B20 GND are connected to the common GND through RJ45" RJ45 is a telephony standard not used for 40 years. If you are talking about the 8P8C connector used for Ethernet it is galvanically isolated and CAN'T connect anything to Gnd.

Comment: I'm not convinced that those readings correlate with the power supply. The DS18B20 has an accuracy of only 0.5°C. How do you know that all 4 sensors have the same temperature? My guess is, they simply don't have the same temperature.

Comment: If you want to test if the deviations are caused by a changing supply voltage, you need to modulate the supply and see if that correlates with the readings.

Comment: Another thing to note: obly the DS18B20 **by Maxim** and the DS18B20**+** by Dallas actually support the parasitic mode you seem to use. Make sure you have one of those or provide the sensor with a stable Vcc on the third pin.